# Kinect v2 Javascript API , cant access ColorCameraSettings members

Tags: javascript, c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

trying to access `WindowsPreview.Kinect.ColorCameraSettings` , show permission denied in console logger for all members , though in MS **[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorcamerasettings.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1)** this object should be accessible , anyone knows what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

seems like one of many other issues found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn758677.aspx  , IR emitters cannot be turned off !! camera color stream cannot be controlled ( exposure , frameinterval .. etc )